# JUnit test doesnt do what expected

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have question about JUnit tests.

I am trying to test my code and for some unknown reason it keeps failing me all the time. This is code I try to test:

```
public void userInputWord() throws Exception{ 
    System.out.println("****Please input your word, 2 to 8 ***");
    System.out.println("**********character strings.**********");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    inputWord = br.readLine();
    setInputWord(inputWord);
    setWordLenght(inputWord.length());          
    System.out.println("***Please input amount of words you***");
    System.out.println("*************want to find*************");
    try{
        stringLadder = br.readLine();
        setLadder(Integer.parseInt(stringLadder));
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("Your input must be integer value.");
    }
    searchForMatch();
}
```

Basically this method is asking user to input two values (starting word and how many words he wants to see as a WordLadder) I am assigning those values to set methods. My JUnit for this class is following:

```
public void testUserInputWord() {
    Generation gener = new Generation();
    StringReader read = new StringReader("broom");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(read);
    gener.setInputWord(scan.toString());
    assertEquals("broom", gener.getInputWord());
}
```

I never wrote JUnit before and just did some research, could anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that you're never calling the code you're trying to test. All you're testing at the moment is the getters and setters (for `ladder` and `inputWord`).

Unfortunately, testing the `userInputWord` method is tricky, because it relies on `System.in`. You need to have a way of "faking" the user input. One option would be to make the method take a `Scanner` or perhaps a `Reader`. You could then create all the appropriate user input via a `StringReader`, so that the method would read the data you'd pre-programmed. You'd then test the results. If other parts of this class need user input too, you may want to change it so that your *constructor* takes something (again, possibly a `Scanner`, possibly a `Reader`) to represent user input. Again, you'd provide the test data when constructing your test instance.

Fundamentally, the idea of "something to provide user input" is a *dependency* for the code you're trying to test - and a lot of the skill of unit testing is working out how to provide dependencies which are under the control of your test. There are lots of approaches to this which are appropriate in different situations - in this case, you can probably just use an existing implementation (`StringReader`) as the underlying data source instead of the console.

Comment: Hi, I tried rewriting using your advice, I am not really sure how should I use scanner input after I read it... could you check my edited JUnit code and let me know?

Comment: @JavaNoob: You shouldn't be setting `inputWord` in your test - the whole point is to test that your `userInputWord` method does that. Also, although you're *creating* the `Scanner`, you're not providing it to the code that you want to test, so presumably that's still reading from `System.in`. You need to change your `userInputWord` method to accept a `Scanner` and read from that, then call that method from your test. Until you've got a call to that method within your test, you're clearly not testing that method...

Answer (score 2):

You say that the JUnit test does not do what you expected. Perhaps you should tell us what exactly you *expected*, so we can tell you why the expectation is not met.

As Jon said, the code snippets you show us do not really belong together. Your test method seems to test the `setInputWord` / `getInputWord` pair of setter and getter. There is no call to `userInputWord` at all.

Also I can see that your test method is prefixed with `test` and does not have any annotation. This is the terribly outdated JUnit 3 style. Please have a look at the [JUnit Cookbook](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm).